# Parse shape movement from createjs tween?

Tags: javascript, createjs, tweenjs

I'm trying to pre-calculate the bounding boxes of objects in a createjs file.
I have a simple recursive loop that loops over the tween.
I'm having trouble understanding how the data is stored.

My understanding is so far:
tween._stephead - the start of the tween
tween._stephead.next - the next tween target, with multiple .next objects
and mixed in between there seem to be some ease objects.

For each of the tween targets, I read the props, and move the bounding box of my shape according to the values x and y.

This seems to work okay for single objects on a tween, but as soon as there are multiple objects in a tween, this falls apart, due to the fact that its stored in an array, and objects not in the array are still visible on screen.

Ive looked over the API and haven't found any other way to do pre-calculation of objects movements... Am I going about this right?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a simpler method, just play the demo though without displaying it to the user.

```
    for (var f=0; f<totalFrames; f++) {
        stage.update();
        var c = exportRoot.numChildren;
        while(c--) {
            var child = exportRoot.children[c];
            ...
        }
    }
```